# What is the right way to include ion-nav-bar in ionic app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, i have declared the ion-nav-bar in the index.html file. This works perfectly, i.e. the ion-nav-bar is shown in all the pages that i want it shown. I am also able to hide it if need be.

But there is one minor problem. Since the ion-nav-bar is declared in the index file, when the app loads, the nav bar shows up for a brief second before loading the login page. I would like to totally hide the nav bar in the index page as well, but if i do that, it will not show up in all other pages. What is the proper way to handle this? Thanks for help. My code as shown:

Index.html:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">      
  <i class="button button-icon custom-back-button"></i>
</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<!--Contents get loaded into ionNavView-->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

code here

Comment: so you don't want a nav bar in the login page, but have one in the rest of the pages?

Comment: No, i dont want the nav bar in the index page to show up. The index page is more like a loading page, not right to have a nav bar showing in there, even though for a second or less.